# Nlmer rises is.numeric(nlpars <- start$nlpars) is not TRUE

Tags: r, nlme

When using nlmer:

```
nlmer(velocity~musclemass+musclewidth+(1|muscletype)+(1|observer))
```

the error:

> Error in nlformula(mc <- match.call()) :    is.numeric(nlpars <-
>   start$nlpars) is not TRUE

arises. What could be wrong with my model?

I did not include a Nonlin(...) part. I tried including this by pasting ~ SSlogis(musclemass, 1, 2, 2) directly after velocity, but still the error arises.

Answer (score 0):

You are fitting a linear model in a function that expects a nonlinear model *and* you are  missing the mixed part. From the man page: a formula of the form ‘resp ~ nlmod ~ meform’ where ‘resp’ is an expression for the response, ‘nlmod’ is the nonlinear model expression and ‘meform’ is the mixed-effects model formula.